# In JavaScript, Why doesn't for in return the contents of Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I get that using a for ... in loop will return all properties of an object, including those from its prototype chain, and using .keys() will give me an array of non-inher (basically for ... in combined with hasOwnProperty) but why doesn't a for ... in loop include things brought in from Object? i.e. why doesn't for .. in include the toString function from Object? Thanks!

Comment: The for...in statement iterates over the **enumerable properties** of an object, in arbitrary order -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: `for..in` loops only iterate over properties that are [defined as `enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). You can inspect that setting with [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, 'toString').enumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).

Answer (score 2):

A property of an object is defined by its key, value and also whether it is configurable, enumerable, writable. A non enumerable property will not show up in for in loops.

When an object property is created like this

```
var myObject = {};
myObject["a"] = 3;
```

It is by default configurable, enumerable and writable. It will show up in for in loops. It is possible to create non enumerable properties with `Object.defineProperty`. You can check if a property is enumerable with `.propertyIsEnumerable`:

```
myObject.propertyIsEnumerable("a"); // --> true
Object.propertyIsEnumerable("toString"); // --> false
```

Comment: That makes prefect sense. I didn't realize that Object's properties were defined as not enumerable. Thanks!